# Phone number validation for specific format

Tags: javascript, regex

I have below regex to check the valid phone number in different formats, it also support Arabic numbers:

```
/^(\+?\s{0,2}([0-9\u0660-\u0669]{1,3}))?[-,.\s]{0,2}\(?[0-9\u0660-\u0669]{1,5}\)?[-,.\s]{0,2}[0-9\u0660-\u0669]{1,5}[-,.\s]{0,2}[0-9\u0660-\u0669]{1,6}\s{0,2}\+?/
```

But this is returning false for one of the valid number `+(91)-20-xxxxxxxx`

Comment: your regex doesn't allow `(` or `)`

Comment: Quite normal, since you don't have anything to match the `(` or `)`. You want to escape those in your regex.

Comment: ohk so how I can modify this regex?

Comment: you allow `(` and `)` later on ... do that

Comment: @JaromandaX can you please modify the regex, actually I am not familiar with regex.

Comment: there's answers posted by people who at least think they know enough about regex to answer this question ... I could tell you what you got wrong, if I were confident enough to tell you how to fix it, I'd have posted an answer rather than a comment :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first optional group that matches a `+` needs the optional `(` and `)`:

```
^(\+?\(?\s{0,2}[0-9\u0660-\u0669]{1,3}\)?)?[-,.\s]{0,2}\(?[0-9\u0660-\u0669]{1,5}\)?[-,.\s]{0,2}[0-9\u0660-\u0669]{1,5}[-,.\s]{0,2}[0-9\u0660-\u0669]{1,6}\s{0,2}\+?
     ^^^                              ^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vF7hW9/1)

Note you might re-check the pattern, the trailing `\+?` looks rather suspicious, and there is no `$` (end of string anchor) at the end of the pattern (if you plan to match the whole string, you need that anchor).